# Making a working hours tracker

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel log file as shown in the image .im using vba to parse through the user columns eg "nxf4" . i need a code that calculates the working hours of each specific user

[image: img1]

Comment: Please provide code you have tried so far as well as the column letters and especially point out which one has the working hours stored (it is not very obvious in your image). And please don't link images from external sources, post them inline in your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, I don't think you need VBA for this - a simple `SUMIFS` should suffice.

Comment: Have you searched on here - there are some questions whith answers that may help you...

Answer (score 0):

Using formulas:

Add a helper column that converts the month, day, hour, minute, second to a datetime (something like `=DATEVALUE(C2&" "&B2&" "&H2)+TIME(D2,E2,F2)`). Copy the usernames into a blank range and remove duplicates (Data > Data Tools). Then use two `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(L:L,I:I,"logoff",K:K,username)-SUMIFS(L:L,I:I,"logon",K:K,username)
```

Using VBA: (this will be noticeably faster with large datasets), use a dictionary and add each logoff datetime and subtract each logon datetime for each user as you loop through the rows. Then output the keys and items of the dictionary to a specified range.